# How to select integer for function

Tags: python

I have some function such as sumssqure of the range number n, if n is integer, it should return the sum value. If n is not integer, should return with some string. It must use
raise ValueError("Sorry, n must be a whole number!").
My codes can works well with any integer n, but has problem when n is not integer. I don't know how to fix it. Many thanks.

```
def sumsquares(n):
    try:
        return sum(i**2 for i in range(0,n+1))
    except ValueError as ve:
        err = str(ve)
    assert err == "Sorry, n must be a whole number!"
sumsquares(2.2)
```

Comment: The `assert` won't work. If there's no error, `err` is not set and it will get an error when trying to compare it. And if there is an error, `err` will be the error message, not the string you're comparing with.

Comment: Why do you not simply test the input to see whether it's an integer?

Comment: The except and assert parts come from instruction, looks I must add those code inside. Maybe I add not correctly? Lost mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return the string you want in the `except` block.

Also, the exception that's raised when you give the wrong type of argument to `range()` is `TypeError`, not `ValueError`.

```
def sumsquares(n):
    try:
        return sum(i**2 for i in range(0,n+1))
    except TypeError as ve:
        return "Sorry, n must be a whole number!"
```

Comment: Many thanks. I tried your code, but failed. If I delete "ValueError as ve:", it works well. How can come out with: ValueError: Sorry, n must be a whole number! Many thanks!

Comment: The exception should be `TypeError`.

Answer (score 0):

If n is a float type , you can add a simple check and return as following

```
if n%1 != 0:
    return 'Float type'
```